# notepad++: changing the config.xml doesn't work

Tags: notepad++

Is it possible that “notepad++” ignores what is written in the modelconfig.xml file?
I have change in this line:  
to replaceBySpace=“yes”
but even after I save the file and open notepad++ again, in the GUI config, when I look at Settings -> Preferences -> Language menu/Tab settings, the box of “replace by space” is unchecked!

why this is happening? And how can I edit the setting (with the config.xml, and not with the GUI)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are changing `config.xml` when Notepad++ is ***not*** running.

Or, if it is running, kill Notepad++ after editing and saving the file, so the `config.xml` isn't auto-saved on exit, because it can overwrite the file, reverting your edits.

Then start Notepad++.

---

Do not edit `config.model.xml`, it is unrelated.

Comment: so what is the file I need to edit? I dont see "config.xml" in notepad++ folder, only confog.model. xml

Comment: @yiffah – find it [under your %APPDATA% directory](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11894/how-to-make-a-full-backup-of-npp-settings) – obviously you have installed Notepad++ that way

Comment: @yiffah - if the answer was helpful Please mark it as accepted by checking green mark as visible in [tour].